# How to choose lins with powershell export-csv

Tags: powershell, export-csv

I am struggling with powershell. I am trying to get the time for some events.
Lets say first the router is booting up, second the router has a login, third the router is up,... router can ping. Unfortunally we cant do everything in one ps1 file. Thus i have to start the script at the event.

so the `$var` variable is first: start
second: login
...

My code looks like this:

```
Get-Date | Select-Object @{ expression={$_.DateTime}; label="$var" } |  Export-Csv -Delimiter ";"  Path C:\Users\Username\Desktop\time.csv -NoTypeInformation -append -Force
```

The csv file is this:

[image]

But it should look like this

[image]

Comment: "im trying to get the time for some events" - then why are you using `Get-Date` to generate the date?

Comment: @kaeptnbalu Are there any updates to this question? Please, take a minute to share with us, if you have already solved this issue or you are facing problem with something.